# How do you have a do-while loop run again with the choice of the user wanting to run it again?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, char, do-while

When using a do-while, while or for loop, I seem to always get infinite loops constantly after I try to ask the user if they would like to run a function again.

```
  #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    
    while (choice == 'y')
    {
        // Do something
        
        // Exits while loop
        
    }
    
    std::cout << "Would you like to do it again?" << std::endl;
    
    std::cin >> choice;
}
```

Is there a line of code I am forgetting?

Comment: You are going to have to provide a better [mcve] demonstrating an infinite loop in action so we can see exactly HOW you are reading the input and trying to act on it. In any case, in the code you have shown, the prompt for the user's `choice` is being performed after the loop is already finished, so it is useless.  Move it *inside* the loop instead.

Comment: Please try to explain the code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially explain when and where ***inside the loop*** you modify `choice` so the loop might end.

Comment: Tell your _rubber duck_ how the while loop exits, **and** what happens _after_ `std::cin >> choice;`

Comment: *"after I try to ask the user if they would like to run a function again"* -- is this accurate for your code snippet? The infinite loop occurs **after** the prompt `Would you like to do it again?` is displayed?? Being precise when describing your symptoms is useful for debugging. The small details matter.

Answer (score 1):

For starters in this context it is better to substitute the while loop for a do-while loop. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    
    do
    {
        // Do something
        
        std::cout << "Would you like to do it again?" << std::endl;
    
        std::cin >> choice;
    } while ( choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y' );
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the question (and input read) should be INSIDE the while loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char choice = 'y';
    
    while (choice == 'y') {
        // Do something

        std::cout << "Would you like to do it again?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
    }
}
```

Update:  Adding the `do-while` loop as suggested by Remy.

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    do {
        // Do something

        std::cout << "Would you like to do it again?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'y');
}
```

Comment: Or, using a `do..while` loop: `char choice; do { ... std::cin >> choice; } while (choice == 'y');`